# I have a dataframe containing arrays, is there a way collect all of the elements and store it in a seperate dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I cant seem to find a way to split all of the array values from the column of a dataframe.

I have managed to get all the array values using this code:
[image]

The dataframe is as follows:
[image]

I want to use value.counts() on the dataframe and I get this[image]

I want the array values that are clubbed together to be split so that I can get the accurate count of every value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), which would create a new row for every value in each list.

```
df_mentioned_id_exploded = pd.DataFrame(df_mentioned_id.explode('entities.user_mentions'))
```

With the above code you would create a new dataframe `df_mentioned_id_exploded` with a single column `entities.user_mentions`, which you could then use `.value_counts()` on.